# Java - sorting using Collections.sort()

Tags: java, sorting, collections, integer, double

I have to write a method to sort both Integers and Doubles.

```
public ArrayList<Number> sortDescending(ArrayList<Number> al){
    Comparator<Number> c=Collections.reverseOrder();
    Collections.sort(al,c);
    return al;
}

public ArrayList<Number> sortAscending(ArrayList<Number> al){
    Collections.sort(al);
    return al;
}
```

The problem is that in sortAscending, the following error occurs:

> Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList). The inferred type Number is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter < T extends Comparable < ? super T>>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use a generic *upper bound* of `Number` intersecting with `Comparable<T>`:

```
public <T extends Number & Comparable<T>> ArrayList<T> sortDescending(ArrayList<T> al){
    Comparator<T> c=Collections.reverseOrder();
    Collections.sort(al,c);
    return al;
}

public <T extends Number & Comparable<T>> ArrayList<T> sortAscending(ArrayList<T> al){
    Collections.sort(al);
    return al;
}
```

All JDK `Numbers` (eg `Float`, `Integer` etc) match this typing.

For the uninitiated, the syntax `<T extends A & B>` is the way you bound `T` to *both* `A` and `B`.

FYI, there is no syntax for "or" logic (nor would it make sense if you think about it)

Comment: FYI:  There's no reason to have a return type on either of your methods, as the List is sorted in place.

Comment: @Matt Rather than "no reason", there are several reasons to have return types: A) To illustrate the implications of typing the method, B) That's what the OP had and C) Returning objects from "non-getter" methods is done when implementing the [fluent API pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)

Answer (score 4):

You are getting the error because number does not implement `Comparable<Number>`. You need to add a generic contstraint so that it extends both number and Comparable. In this case:

```
public <T extends Number & Comparable<T>> ArrayList<T> sortAscending(ArrayList<T> al){
    Collections.sort(al);
    return al;
}
```